# Order of the product of two elements of a group with known order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that a group $G$ contains $2$ elements $a$ and $b$ such that $ab=ba$, and element $a$ has order $4$, and element $b$ has order $3$. How can we determine the order of $ab$.

I thought this seemed pretty interesting, but how can we really determine this?

Comment: why is this true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is in every book on abstract algebra: if $ab=ba,\mathrm{ord}(a)=k,\mathrm{ord}(b)=m$ and $k,m$ are co-prime, then $\mathrm{ord}(ab)=km$.

Indeed, $(ab)^{km}=1$, so $\mathrm{ord}(ab)\,\vert\,km$. On the other hand since $\gcd(k,m)=1$ there exist $u,v$ such that $ku+mv=1$. Then $ku\,\mathrm{ord}(ab)+mv\,\mathrm{ord}(ab)=\mathrm{ord}(ab)$. Then

$$1=(ab)^{\mathrm{ord}(ab)}=(ab)^{ku\,\mathrm{ord}(ab)+mv\,\mathrm{ord}(ab)}=a^{mv\,\mathrm{ord}(ab)}=b^{ku\,\mathrm{ord}(ab)}.$$

Therefore $k$ divides $mv\,\mathrm{ord}(ab)$. Since $k$ is coprime with $mv$, $k$ divides $\mathrm{ord}(ab)$. Similarly $m$ divides $\mathrm{ord}(ab)$. Since $\gcd(k,m)=1$, $km$ divides $\mathrm{ord}(ab)$. Thus $\mathrm{ord}(ab)=km$.